How to write a function reflecting an inserted value in one table in any other table having a certain column in Postgres?
Lets say, I have a set of Postgres tables in a schema my users may work on. Each table looks a bit different from each other - e.g. one table has a field called "name", another table has a field called "address" in addition. Some have a "geom" column as they are using the PostGIS extension. There are only 3 columns that all these tables have in common:

an incrementing column "id" which must not be NULL
a column called "active" which is a boolean (users can only see "active" records thanks to row level security)
a column "status" which is set to NULL when "active" is TRUE (at least the user only may see records having NULL values).

There is a trigger assigned to each table ensuring to log all inserts, updates and deletes made by my users in a history table. There are a few other triggers that are related to these tables but that number varies.
To make this more "visible", lets say one of my tables is called "infrastructure" and has the following fields assigned:
id, name, address, geom, project_id, active, status_id.
Another table is called "system" with a slightly different number of columns:
id, name, description, comments, project_id, active, status_id.
There are a couple of tables left in that schema my users may work on but for the sake of this example, these 2 tables may suffice.
What is my objective:
As an admin, I want to update the "status_id" column of each table using my table "status" in my admin schema:
id, project_id, status_text, comment (id is an autoincrement field as well)
So every insert in that "status"-table should lead to the following:

for all tables (not views!) having the column "status_id" all records being active should be duplicated. For the duplicated cases, the "status_id" should be set to the autoincremented column "id" from table "status" where I made my manual insert as admin before. Furthermore, for these duplications in the tables, the "active" column should be set to "False".
the triggers associated with the table should be temporarily disabled avoiding anything like history logs for example since this is an admin induced action. After the duplication of the records in each table, the triggers originally associated with the table should get enabled again.

How am I achieving that in the most generic way? I thought on writing a trigger-function related to my table "status" firing whenever a new insert is made. This would then

loop through all tables having a column called "status_id"
disabling the triggers associated with the table
making the duplication of the null-value status-records
setting column "active" to False and "status_id" to "id" of table "status" for the duplicated rows
Re-enable all triggers again


Please review [mre] and add concrete examples (abstract descriptions are not adequate). The described approach is not viable. Disabling triggers affects all sessions: any concurrent actions in other sessions on the affected tables will occur without firing the triggers, which is likely not the desired behavior. Why are you trying to do this? What is the use case?
